# How does GoLand of JetBrains find the implementations of interface?

Tags: go, vim, editor, jetbrains-ide, goland

As I know, it's basing on Guru for vim-go to find the implementations or usage which needs to compile the whole project as a premise. Otherwise, GoLand doesn't need to do that, but how?

Comment: It does it like guru does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this task may look rather trivial, GoLand uses some tricks to perform it more efficiently. Let's go step by step to explore how it works.

0. When one opens a project for the first time, the IDE performs so-called indexing. In particular, it stores all the method and method spec names as well as the number of their parameters.
1. At the beginning of the search, GoLand takes method specs of the interface and finds one with the biggest number of parameters. This is a performance optimization. The idea behind it is that methods with many parameters occur less often in the code, so the IDE needs to check just a few of them.
2. It's time to use the index. For the chosen method spec, the IDE finds all corresponding methods. The scope is taken into account, so for a private interface, for instance, it's much smaller.
3. For each method, GoLand resolves its type and checks whether it implements the interface. This is the moment when all interface's method specs are taken into account.
4. Not only structures can implement interfaces but other interfaces, too. As the next steps, the IDE looks for all corresponding method specifications, that is, method specifications with the same name and number of parameters. There's a separate index that's responsible for this.
5. For each method spec, its interface is taken and checked. No resolution is involved this time as it's enough to traverse a syntax tree up to find an interface of an arbitrary method spec.

That's basically the algorithm. There are a few more implementation details to make it works faster, but they don't affect results.

Answer (score 1):

GoLand relies on the [IntelliJ Platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/opensource/idea/) and a set of custom written tooling bundled as [a custom language plugin](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support.html) on top of it to handle indexing, parsing, navigation and editing code.